# Mindbodyonline Checkoutshoppingcart API

Tags: php, api, cakephp, soap-client, soapserver

I am getting some issue in mindbodyonline API , While intigrating CHECKOUT Shoping CART API,

Here is my API Code

```
$mbResult = $mb->CheckoutShoppingCart(array(
            'Test' => false,    // Here 
            'ClientID' => 100015377,
//            'CartID' => 123, 
           'InStore' => true,
            'SendEmail' => true,
            'CartItems' => array(
                'CartItem' => array(
                    'Quantity' => 1,
                    'Item' => new SoapVar(
                            array('ID' => '1357'), SOAP_ENC_ARRAY, 'Service', 'http://clients.mindbodyonline.com/api/0_5'
                    ),
                    'DiscountAmount' => 0
                )
            ),
            'Payments' => array(
                'PaymentInfo' => new SoapVar(
                        array(
                    'CreditCardNumber' => '4111111111111111',
                    'ExpYear' => '2016',
                    'ExpMonth' => '06',
                    'Amount' => '131',
                    'BillingAddress' => '123 Happy Ln',
                    'BillingPostalCode' => '93405',
                    "ID" => 21
                        ), SOAP_ENC_ARRAY, 'CreditCardInfo', 'http://clients.mindbodyonline.com/api/0_5'
                )
            )
        ));
```

Getting this reponse from API

SAOP Response :

```
stdClass Object
(
[CheckoutShoppingCartResult] => stdClass Object
(
[Status] => InvalidParameters
[ErrorCode] => 9999
[Message] => Card Authorization Failed DECLINED:1000410001:Invalid merchant:

[XMLDetail] => Full
[ResultCount] => 0
[CurrentPageIndex] => 0
[TotalPageCount] => 0
)    
)
```

Whenever I use test mode is true commented above I am getting SOAP Response is :

```
stdClass Object
(
    [CheckoutShoppingCartResult] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Status] => Success
            [ErrorCode] => 200
            [XMLDetail] => Full
            [ResultCount] => 0
            [CurrentPageIndex] => 0
            [TotalPageCount] => 0
            [ShoppingCart] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ID] => cbae7ca5-5b1b-46b8-ab82-e8fee591e238
                    [CartItems] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [CartItem] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [Item] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [Price] => 130.0000
                                            [OnlinePrice] => 130.0000
                                            [TaxRate] => 0
                                            [ProductID] => 1357
                                            [ID] => 123456789
                                            [Name] => 1 Month Unlimited
                                            [Count] => 99999
                                        )

                                    [DiscountAmount] => 0
                                    [ID] => 1
                                    [Quantity] => 1
                                )

                        )

                    [SubTotal] => 130
                    [DiscountTotal] => 0
                    [TaxTotal] => 0
                    [GrandTotal] => 130
                )

        )

)
```

But purchased service is showing in mindbodyonline sandbox account.

Any one help be appreciable.

Thanks

Comment: You might want to improve your question by adding an actual question, and more details. Also it seems like this question would have more chances to be answered by the specific provider's support, if such exists.

Comment: I have updated my question please review and suggest me .

Answer (score 0):

```
$mindb              = new MINDBODY_API(); 
print_r($mindb->GetClientContracts(array('ClientID'=>100000528))); 
    $checkout   = $mindb->checkoutShoppingCart(
                            array( 'ClientID' => 100000528,
                                    'CartID' => 124, 
                                    'InStore' => true,
                                    'Test' => true,    // Here 
                                    'SendEmail' => true,
                                    'CartItems' => array(
                                        'CartItem' => array(
                                            'Quantity' => 1,
                                            'Item' => new SoapVar(
                                                    array('ID' => 124), SOAP_ENC_ARRAY, 'Service', 'http://clients.mindbodyonline.com/api/0_5'
                                            ),
                                            'DiscountAmount' => 0
                                        )
                                    ),
                                    'Payments' => array(
                                        'PaymentInfo' => new SoapVar(
                                                array(
                                                    'CreditCardNumber' => '4242424242424242',
                                                    'ExpYear' => '2019',
                                                    'ExpMonth' => '03',
                                                    'Amount' => 0,
                                                    'BillingAddress' => 'indore',
                                                    'BillingPostalCode' => '93401',
                                                    'BillingCity'=>'indore',
                                                    'BillingState'=>'CA',
                                                    'BillingName'=>'Amin321 Aminkhanb321',
                                                    //'ID'=>205
                                                ), SOAP_ENC_ARRAY, 'CreditCardInfo', 'http://clients.mindbodyonline.com/api/0_5'
                                        )
                                    )
                                ));


    print_r($checkout);
```